# Como escrever do popup para a pagina pai?

Tags: c#, asp.net, popup, itextsharp

Estou com dúvida na seguinte situação, estou devolvendo um PDF para o popUp(Pagina filho). gostaria de fechar esse Popup e Escrever(Write(pdfDoc) na pagina pai)

```
//A propriedade ContentType especifica o tipo de conteúdo HTTP para a resposta. 
//Se nenhum ContentType for especificado, o padrão é text / HTML.
Response.ContentType = "application/pdf"; 

//O método AddHeader adiciona um novo cabeçalho e valor HTML à resposta enviada
//ao cliente. Ele não substitui um cabeçalho existente do mesmo nome. Depois que 
//um cabeçalho foi adicionado, não pode ser removido.
Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=NotaFiscal.pdf");

//Resposta do servidor, escrever um fluxo de saida (.PDF)
Response.Write(pdfDoc); 
Response.End();
```

Como mostra na imagem PopUp(Preto) Pagina Pai(parte branca)
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Você não está escrevendo o pdf em uma pop, você está respondendo o arquivo para download, ao invés disso você quer renderizá-lo na tela?

Comment: Gostaria de responder na pagina pai